# How to set a DependenceProperty if another DependencyProperty changes?

Tags: c#, wpf, custom-controls, dependency-properties

This is my solution structure:

[image: solution structure]

My MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="ExampleApp.Views.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:paretoPlot="clr-namespace:ParetoPlotCustomControl;assembly=ParetoPlotCustomControl"
        xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/"
        prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <Button Command="{Binding CreateNewParetoCommand}" Height="50" Width="100">Create Pareto</Button>
            <paretoPlot:ParetoPlotControl Width="Auto" Height="300" ParetoData="{Binding CustomParetoData}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

My MainWindowViewModel.cs:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using MathNet.Spatial.Euclidean;
using OxyPlot;
using Pareto;
using Prism.Commands;
using Prism.Mvvm;

namespace ExampleApp.ViewModels
{
    public class MainWindowViewModel : BindableBase
    {
        private Pareto.Pareto _customParetoData;
        public Pareto.Pareto CustomParetoData
        {
            get { return _customParetoData; }
            set { SetProperty(ref _customParetoData, value); }
        }

        private DelegateCommand _createNewParetoCommand;
        public DelegateCommand CreateNewParetoCommand =>
            _createNewParetoCommand ?? (_createNewParetoCommand = new DelegateCommand(ExecuteCreateNewParetoCommand));

        void ExecuteCreateNewParetoCommand() => CustomParetoData = CreateARandomPareto();

        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            //CustomParetoData = CreateARandomPareto();
        }

        private Pareto.Pareto CreateARandomPareto()
        {
            var pareto = // Irrelevant code.
            return pareto;
        }
    }
}
```

My ParetoPlotControl.cs:

```
public class ParetoPlotControl : Control
    {
        public Pareto.Pareto ParetoData
        {
            get => (Pareto.Pareto)GetValue(ParetoDataProperty);
            set { UpdateParetoPlot(); SetValue(ParetoDataProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ParetoDataProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("ParetoData", typeof(Pareto.Pareto),
                typeof(ParetoPlotControl),
                new PropertyMetadata(new Pareto()));

        internal PlotModel OxyPlotModel
        {
            get { return (PlotModel)GetValue(OxyPlotModelProperty); }
            private set { SetValue(OxyPlotModelProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty OxyPlotModelProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("OxyPlotModel", typeof(PlotModel),
                typeof(ParetoPlotControl), new PropertyMetadata(new PlotModel{Title = "Pareto Plot"}));

        static ParetoPlotControl()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(ParetoPlotControl),
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(ParetoPlotControl)));
        }

        private void UpdateParetoPlot()
        {
            OxyPlotModel.Series.Clear();
            OxyPlotModel.Axes.Clear();
            OxyPlotModel.Axes.Add(new LinearAxis{Position = AxisPosition.Bottom, Title = "1 - TCP"});
            OxyPlotModel.Axes.Add(new LinearAxis{Position = AxisPosition.Left, Title = "NTCP"});
            var paretoPointSeries = GetParetoPointSeries() // Irrelevant here.;
            foreach (var series in paretoPointSeries) OxyPlotModel.Series.Add(series);
            OxyPlotModel.InvalidatePlot(true);
        }
    }
```

and my Generic.xaml:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ParetoPlotCustomControl"
    xmlns:oxy="http://oxyplot.org/wpf">
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:ParetoPlotControl}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:ParetoPlotControl}" >
                    <Grid>
                        <oxy:PlotView Model="{TemplateBinding OxyPlotModel}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

What I would like to happen is that:

1. MainWindowViewModel has only access to the ParetoData property, but not to OxyPlotModel.
2. When MainWindowViewModel changes the Pareto, the OxyPlotModel shall be updated with the new Pareto.

**Problem is that the UpdatePareoPlot() is never executed. How can I achieve this?**

I tried using a PropertyChangedCallback for ParetoDataProperty, but then I cannot access OxyPlotModel, because it is not static. If I turn OxyPlotModel to a normal property instead of DependencyProperty, I cannot bind it to Generic.xaml...

Comment: The PropertyChangedCallback of a dependency property gets a DependencyObject as first argument. That is the object on which the property was changed, and can be cast to the type of your control, e.g. like `var control = (ParetoPlotControl)o;`. You can then access any other property or method of the control instance. And you must have that PropertyChangedCallback anyway, because it has to call the UpdateParetoPlot() method. That method call must not be made in the property setter, because there are scenarios where the setter is not called, but where WPF directly calls SetValue.

Comment: ... and the second argument of PropertyChangedCallback contains old and new values of associated property

Comment: Now I tried 

```private static void PropertyChangedCallback(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var control = (ParetoPlotControl)d;
            var newPareto = e.NewValue as Pareto.Pareto;
            control.ParetoData = newPareto;
            control.UpdateParetoPlot(newPareto);
        }
```

But `newPareto` is null at the beginning and when MainWindowViewModel changes CustomParetoData nothing happens.

Comment: That's a different problem. You might be setting the property on a different view model instance than the one to which the view is bound.

Comment: How could that possible happen and how can I find out? I am using the Prism WPF template without any changes to the initialization process.

Comment: The `Mode=TwoWay` in MainWindow.xaml was missing! Now it works! Thank you so much!